# Unable to change date format in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am new for Angular. I want to change date format that is sent from datepicker input.

Here is my code,

```
$scope.savePlaylist = function(s){
  //s= 02-November-2015
  var startDate = $filter('date')(s,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59'); //it return 02-November-2015
  var test = $filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59');//it works!
};
```

So, I tried [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment),

```
$scope.savePlaylist = function(s){
  //s= 02-November-2015
  var startDate = $filter('amDateFormat')(s,'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'); //it return empty
  var test = $filter('amDateFormat')(new Date(),'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59');//it works!
};
```

I really need help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: dint get your problem. do you want to change 02-November-2015 to YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59 format?

Comment: make your problem statement more clear .

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign date("s") to new date object and pass it to $filter. That will solve your problem.

```
$scope.savePlaylist = function(s){
  //s= 02-November-2015
  var dt = new Date(s);
  var startDate = $filter('date')(dt,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59'); //it return 02-November-2015
  var test = $filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59');//it works!
};
```

Comment: It told 02-November-2015 is an Invalid Date

Answer (score 0):

It cannot use 02-November-2015 to convert to other format. I changed it into
  **dd MMMM yyyy**

It can work now. Thanks.